# How to get web site user's Windows login name from stored procedure invoked through website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, windows-authentication

I have a web page that runs under an account named, `WebUser` (IIS runs under this account)

Now the problem here is that, when the webpage is accessed by users (intranet), 
users are authenticated through *Windows Authentication*.

The webpage calls a stored procedure, `SaveClientInfo`.
When I was trying to get the user's name (say, **User1**) who was calling `SaveClientInfo`, 
I was getting **WebUser** instead of **User1** through [`SYSTEM_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

**Is there a way to get *User1* from `SaveClientInfo` without having to pass in the user name to the stored procedure?**

Here is the relevant piece of sproc definition

```
create procedure SaveClientInfo
    @ClientID int
    ... --; other parameters
as
begin
    declare @UserName sysname
    --; returns the name of user name that IIS runs under
    --; But I would like to log the name of the person 
    --; who is accesing the site through Windows Authentication
    select  @UserName = SYSTEM_USER 

    --; Save client data and the person who saved the info
    ...
end
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use impersonation in your web app, so the web application connects as the Windows authenticated user, no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the name of the user from the SQL should just give you the username associated with the connection - typically, the user account used by ASP.NET.

On the .NET side, You can use (C#)

```
string s = Environment.User.Identity.Name
```

to retrieve the name of the user logged into your site. We use this to track who's making changes to the db through our admin site, among other thngs.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to create a new parameter like @UserName for *every* sprocs that saves information.

Comment: The problem is, as Chris J pointed out, that the logged in user isn't talking to the SQL server. ASP.NET is, using its own permissions. You're going to *have* to pass some parameter in identifying the user. Whether that's a session ID, username or what have you, there's no real way to avoid this.
Also, IMHO, doing so is poor database and DAL design.